# how to use data of a text list field to draw a canvas image?

Tags: entities

I'm working on a website, where some information has to be drawn like a graph on a canvas. I have the javascript to draw the picture, but for input I need the values of a field (List/Text) initialized by check boxes.

What I need is a way to get the values from the field of the node and draw a canvas image with the javascript code I have but I cannot figure out how..

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you need to get the value in the browser on the client side so you would need to use jQuery (you can pass the value from the backend to the front end but it won't change if a user changes it unless it is saved or the page is reloaded) and you would need something in this page: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-test-check-if-checkbox-checked.html?m=1 to test of a checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is jQuery. The comment above written by burnsjeremy

'I guess you need to get the value in the browser on the client side so you would need to use jQuery (you can pass the value from the backend '

thanks, burnsjeremy